# Mac OS X Mavericks opens Finder in the same view as an external drive

Tags: macos, mac, finder

Whenever I open a new finder window it opens up as if it's an external drive.  I.e. there's no side navigation bar and clicking through to each folder opens up a new window.

[image]

Any suggestions would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

New finder windows in OS X 10.9 remember the view settings of previous windows.

To fix this, from Finder:

1. View > Show Toolbar (<kbd>cmd</kbd>-<kbd>opt</kbd>-<kbd>T</kbd>)
2. View > Show Sidebar (<kbd>cmd</kbd>-<kbd>opt</kbd>-<kbd>S</kbd>)

If your problem is that subsequent finder windows don't retain the toolbar/sidebar view, then I think your finder preferences might be corrupt. Try following instructions here: http://www.thexlab.com/faqs/finder.html

Comment: I just needed to do `cmd`-`opt`-`T` to get it to work – thanks!